# Can I sample from a multivariate normal when I can only compute matrix-vector products?

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, sparse

I want to sample from a distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ where all I have is the ability to calculate $\Sigma v$ for all $v$.

Is there any algorithm such that I can compute $Lu$ for any $u$ such that $LL^{T} = \Sigma$ ? Or in general a way I can sample from this distribution where all I have is a function $f(v) = \Sigma v$ ?

Comment: If you can compute $\Sigma v$ for all $v$ then you can compute $\Sigma$ then its Cholesky root $L$. Taking $v$ as being the $i$-th column of the identiy matrix brings the $i$-th  column of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Comment: I should have mentioned that $\Sigma$ is too large to fit in memory.